# Connecting Two computers via Ethernet WHILE both are connected LAN?

Tags: networking, ethernet

So I'm planning on getting a new computer pretty soon, I currently have a iMac 2016 model and the computer I plan to get next is a PC. I want to be able to share files easily between them since I'll be doing a ton of video editing and whatnot. I've looked up methods of connecting them via ethernet cable which I would want to do. But If I got a LAN splitter adapter would I be able to have them connected to each other AND to ethernet at the same time?

Comment: Why dont you just buy a simple switch?

Comment: All you have to do is connect them both to your router. Then they will automatically also be connected to each other since all devices connected to the router are part of the same private network.

Comment: Not LAN splitter but a switch. (LAN splitters are a piece of trash that is sold to the technologically uninformed). All home-grade routers have a four port switch built into them (combo device).